# Proof: For all real numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a < b$ then $a < \frac{a+b}{2} < b$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers in which $a < b$. By the definition of midpoint, $a <m < b$ for some real number $m$ where $m$ is the midpoint. Then:
> **Case 1:**
> $a<b$ 
> $a+a<b+a$
> $2a<b+a$
> **$\frac{2a}{2}<\frac{b+a}{2}$**
> $a<\frac{b+a}{2} $
> **Case 2:** 
> $a<b$ 
> $b+a<b+b$ 
> $b+a<2b$ 
> $\frac{b+a}{2}<\frac{2b}{2}$ 
> $\frac{b+a}{2}<b$ 
> Note that $a<\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $\frac{a+b}{2} <b$, therefore $a <\frac{a+b}{2}< b$ is valid.

---

The problem that I have is whether or not the definition of midpoint is necessary.

> By the definition of midpoint, a <m < b for some real number m where m is the midpoint.

And if there are missing definition i Should add to the proof.

Usually, when writing a direct proof, I want to know the definition of the concept I am working with. This is easy to do when writing the definition of odd, even, rational numbers, etc. The problem I always face is not knowing what definition to use when writing about concepts that don't have one specific definition.

Comment: I wouldn’t write “case,” that has a different meaning in proofs

Comment: Just use the difference it is just direct...

Comment: @ Jules Besson  can you explain in more detail what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do think it is necessary to define the midpoint of $a$ and $b$.  All your proof shows is that the number $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is between $a$ and $b$. But there are other numbers between $a$ and $b$. For example, $\frac{2a+b}{3}$ is between $a$ and $b$, as I'm sure you can prove.

So there does arise a question: Were you only asked to prove that the number $\frac{a+b}{2}$ lies between $a$ and $b$? Or were you instead asked to prove that the midpoint of $a$ and $b$ lies between $a$ and $b$?

The key point here is that if your proof does use the concept of the midpoint of the interval $[a,b]$, then midpoint should be defined: it is a number $m$ having the property that the distance between $a$ and $m$ is equal to the distance between $m$ and $b$. Here I am using the ordinary distance formula along the real number line, where the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $|x-y|$.

If we adopt that definition, and if your desire is to prove that the midpoint is between $a$ and $b$, then your proof is not yet complete: having proved that $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is between $a$ and $b$, you must still prove that the distance between $a$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is equal to the distance between $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $b$. In other words, you must prove the equation $\left| \frac{a+b}{2} - a \right| = \left| b - \frac{a+b}{2} \right|$

Comment: {"So there does arise a question: Were you only asked to prove that the number a+b/2
 lies between a and b? Or were you instead asked to prove that the midpoint of a
 and b lies between a and b?"}                                                                                          
 I want to proof (if a<b then a<a+b/2<b) without using midpoint. the reason i choose midpoint was because i don't know which definition to use. 
 .

Comment: so, the former is what i want to prove.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your sentence "the reason i choose midpoint was because i don't know which definition to use". Definition ***of what***?

Comment: i meant to say that every proof must have a section dedicated to defining the terms used in the proof.  for example: "by definition odd, n is odd ⇔ ∃an integer k such that n = 2k + 1." so, i want something similar to proof: for all real numbers a and b, if a<b then a<a+b/2<b
 .

Comment: Well, if you do not need to use the concept of "midpoint" in the proof, then you do not need to define it. Perhaps one might wish to make a comment to aid the reader's intuition, something like *Note that $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the midpoint of the segment $[a,b]$*, but for intuitive comments that play no part in the logic of the proof it is unnecessary to provide formal definitions.

Comment: Thats always an issue I have when writing a proof. I tend to know what's needed in the proof algebra wise but don't know how to add comments to make it intuitive to readers. so, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you don't need that definition; you never even used it.

Also don't separate your working into cases like that, that means you're dealing with mutually exclusive scenarios, like:

- $a>0$ and $b>0$
- $a>0$ and $b<0$
- $a<0$ and $b>0$
- $a<0$ and $b<0$

Comment: so, if remove that definition, what should I replace it with? or is the proof finished without it?

Comment: well you never used it, so removing it doesn't change your proof.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

$$a\lt b\implies a+a\lt a+b\lt b+b\implies\frac{a+a}{2}\lt\frac{a+b}{2}\lt\frac{b+b}{2}\implies a\lt\frac{a+b}{2}\lt b$$